# Codeigniter image_thumb() stops execution

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd2

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.0 , apache 2.4.17, PHP 5.6.16.

When I need the thumbnail of any image I  use the image_thumb() function.

> But when I upload the image which has size more than 3 MB and then
>   tries to  get the thumbnail at that time execution is terminated
>   without any error(error_reporting is ON).

I trace it and found **resize()function** called inside the image_thumb() function that is terminating execution.

So is it any Server issue?

Comment: use   echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); to check what kind of error it is

Comment: No, it will not work because before resize() function everything is fine so we have not any error. We have to put display_errors() function after resize() function but execution stops at resize() function so it will not execute. So we can't get any error.